# replaceFirst , Why can't special symbols be replaced?

Tags: java, regex

replaceFirst   , Why can't special symbols be replaced?

System.out.println(cal); // 1 * 1 + 1 <==== ???

```
package com;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String cal = "[aaa] * [aaa] + [bbb]";

        int cnt = StringUtils.countMatches(cal, "[");

        String delStr = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
            delStr = cal.substring(cal.indexOf("["), cal.indexOf("]") + 1);
            cal = cal.replaceFirst("["+delStr +"]", "1");
        }

        System.out.println(cal); // 1 * 1 + 1 <==== ???
    }
}
```

Comment: You should try telling us what the code is supposed to do, [] are special characters in regular expressions and need to be escaped, check out regex at: 

https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_regex.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special symbols which are used in the regular expressions need to be either escaped using `\` or entire expression should be treated as a string literal with the help of `Pattern.quote` which basically surrounds the regex with the pair of `\Q` and `\E`.

Also, in the presented code `delStr` would include the pair of the square brackets, thus the replacement should occur for the regexp `[[aaa]]`, and unexpected match -- first `a` in the first occurrence of `[aaa]` -- is found and replaced for such pattern instead of implied replacement.  Then for the following iterations the `cal` looks like `[1aa] * [aaa] + [bbb]` and `cal.indexOf("[")` bring the same first occurrence several times.

So, the following escape of the special symbols described above works fine:

```java
String delStr = "";

for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    delStr = cal.substring(cal.indexOf("["), cal.indexOf("]") + 1);

    cal = cal.replaceFirst("\\Q" + delStr + "\\E", "1"); // literal mode
    // or cal = cal.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(delStr), "1");
}
```

Also, this solution may be refactored to completely get rid of the loop and `String::indexOf` / `String::replaceFirst` methods, because the *implied* result means that **all** the substrings between `[` and `]` including the brackets should be replaced with `1`, that is, `String::replaceAll` would do the entire job:

```java
cal = cal.replaceAll("\\[[^]]*\\]", "1"); // 1 * 1 + 1
```

Comment: Thank you. It's settled thanks to you.String cal = "[aaa] * [aaa] + [bbb]";

  int cnt = StringUtils.countMatches(cal, "[");

  String delStr = "";

  for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
   delStr = StringUtils.substringBetween(cal, "[", "]");
   cal = cal.replaceFirst("\\[" + delStr + "\\]", "1");
  }

  System.out.println(cal); // 1 * 1 + 1